# stop streamwriter writer and convert to string

Tags: c#, streamwriter

i want to pull git log with cmd panel. this is relatively easy to do with

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;

process.StartInfo = info;
process.Start();
using (StreamWriter writer = process.StandardInput){
  if (writer.BaseStream.CanWrite){
      writer.WriteLine("cd C:\\Users\\rene.krause\\source\\repos\\...");
      writer.WriteLine("git log --pretty=oneline");
  }
}
```

I can't exit the streamwriter and convert it to a string to further process the necessary data.
Can someone help me please.

I've searched the web, but haven't found the right solution.

Comment: Why do you start cmd.exe instead of directly launching git.exe?

Comment: you want to use the output of `git log` in your code?